# INNER JOIN third table

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication, phpmyadmin

here is code

```
SELECT profile_friends.friends_friend_id,
       members.name,
       profile_friends.friends_member_id,
       members.member_id
FROM profile_friends
INNER JOIN members ON profile_friends.friends_friend_id=members.member_id
```

how can i add third table and row to this

profile_portal  pp_main_photo

Comment: what column do you want to join it to?

Comment: profile_portal rand row pp_main_photo

Answer (score 0):

Add a second join to jour statement.

```
SELECT profile_friends.friends_friend_id, members.name, profile_friends.friends_member_id,members.member_id,pp_main_photo
FROM profile_friends
INNER JOIN members
ON profile_friends.friends_friend_id=members.member_id
INNER JOIN profile_portal on <condition>
```

Comment: Or..
`SELECT profile_friends.friends_friend_id, members.name, profile_friends.friends_member_id,members.member_id,pp_main_photo
FROM profile_friends, profile_portal, members where profile_friends.friends_friend_id=members.member_id
AND <condition>;`

Comment: what means "<condition>"

Comment: @user2779438 The join condition, with only the name of the table i can not seen how the tables belong to gether.

Comment: $mid = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['member_id']);
$res = mysql_query("


SELECT profile_friends.friends_friend_id, members.name, profile_friends.friends_member_id,members.member_id
FROM profile_friends
INNER JOIN members
ON profile_friends.friends_friend_id=members.member_id


WHERE friends_member_id  = '$mid'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

Comment: that code don`t help to understand how the tables belong together. add create statements of the tables or the database model.

Comment: I am not sure but condition can be `pp_member_id = member_id`

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

it's works :) but one more question

how show message if nothing to show from db message name "you dont have any friend"

here is php code

http://codepad.org/lNEAafej

Comment: @user2779438 If it works, accept the answer please. Can you show wich mysql interface do you use? pdo or mysqli? Logical aks the number of rows, if 0 no rows are found.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INNER JOIN profile_portal ON <YOUR CONDITIONS>
```

AND ABOUT ERROR :
$res does not have the data fro resultset. So please check query whether it return the value.